# analysis of the performance of the mongoDB database, in-memory database redis and in-memory database apache ignite in displaying data

Tags: mongodb, redis, jmeter, apacheignite

Hi I am doing research to compare the performance of the mongoDB database with the in-memory database redis and the in-memory database apache ignite in displaying data.
in this research I will use the Apache jmeter application as a testing tool, but here I really don't know how to use jmeter as an automatic testing tool.

now I have completed the test environment, by creating 3 docker containers for each database, and I have created python code to display data in each database.

but now I don't know how to get the python code that I have created to be tested using jmeter.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter cannot "test" the Python code, you should rather use [Python profilers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html) for this.

When it comes to using JMeter (or any other load testing tool) always think from the end user perspective and simulate the load which as it should come from either real users using real browsers or upstream applications.

If your end product is Python API and you want to test it in a multithreaded manner it might be a better idea to consider using [Locust](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/locust-load-testing) tool instead of JMeter.